# boto3 gives InvalidBucketName error for valid bucket names on S3 with custom url

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I am trying to write a python script for basic get/put/delete/list operations on S3. I am using a cloudian S3 object storage and not AWS. To set the boto3 resource, I set the endpoint and keys like this -

```
URL = 'http://ip:80'

s3_resource = boto3.resource ('s3', endpoint_url=URL,
   aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
   aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY,
   region_name='region1')
```

I have created some test buckets MANUALLY with following names that pass valid S3 bucket names constraints:

- test-bucket-0
- test-bucket-1
- sample-bucket
- testbucket

However, when I try to create a bucket from python code, I get the following error repeatedly -

```
# >>> client.list_buckets()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
#     return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
#   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
#     raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidBucketName) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The specified bucket is not valid.
```

Being very new to boto3, I am really not sure what boto3 is expecting. I have tried various combinations for creating connections to the S3 service such as using `client` instead of `resource`, but the problem is consistent.

A few other S3 connections I tried are these :

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
        endpoint_url='http://10.43.235.193:80',
        aws_access_key_id = 'aaa',                                                                                                                                              
        aws_secret_access_key = 'sss',
        config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
        region_name='region1')
```

```
conn = boto3.connect_s3(                                                                                                                                                       
    aws_access_key_id = 'aaa',                                                                                                                                              
    aws_secret_access_key = 'sss',                                                                                                                                       
    host = '10.43.235.193',                                                                                                                                                       
    port = 80,                                                                                                                                                              
    is_secure = False,                                                                                                                                                        
)
```

```
from boto3.session import Session
session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id='aaa',
    aws_secret_access_key='sss',
    region_name='region1'
)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
client = session.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://10.43.235.193:80') # s3-region1.example.com
```

```
s3_client = boto3.client ('s3', 
   endpoint_url=s3_endpoint,
   aws_access_key_id = 'aaa',
   aws_secret_access_key = 'sss',
   region_name='region1')
```

The python-script is running inside a container and the same pod that runs s3 container. Therefore IP is accessible from 1 container to another. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Do NOT put your access credentials in StackOverflow. You should immediately invalid those credentials so that nobody can use them! FYI, you should store credentials in a configuration file via the `aws configure` command rather than putting them in your code.

Comment: Sorry, but exactly what is your question/problem? You said that you successfully created some buckets, but then creating other buckets failed? Did they _all_ fail, or only certain bucket names? Can you describe this situation in more detail? Also, what is the IP address starting with `10.`? That is a private IP address that is only accessible from within the network. Is it the address of your Cloudian Server within your network?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks you for the suggestion but those keys are dummy. I created buckets manually. IP is `10.` is because its running in kubernetes cluster. so the client application is running in 1 container can talk to s3 service running in another container.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the server is running inside my Kubernetes cluster as a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My finding is very weird. Having an error as `InvalidBucketName` is super misleading though and I found lots of many thread on boto3 github about this. But as it turns out, most of the users are of AWS and not on-prem private cloud S3 so that did not help much.

For me, having IP ex. 10.50.32.5 as an S3 endpoint in the configuration while creating s3_client is not working. Therefore having endpoint set like this -

```
s3_client = boto3.client ('s3', 
   endpoint_url='http://10.50.32.5:80',
   aws_access_key_id = 'AAA',
   aws_secret_access_key = 'SSS',
   region_name='region1')
```

is failing.

**How did I fix this?**

I added a DNS entry into /etc/hosts; i.e. a mapping of IP and S3-endpoint URL like this -

```
10.50.32.5   s3-region1.example.com
```

And then created an S3 client using boto like this -

```py
s3_client = boto3.client ('s3', 
   endpoint_url=s3_endpoint,
   aws_access_key_id = 'AAA',
   aws_secret_access_key = 'BBB',
   region_name='region1')
```

And it worked.